# How to apply similarity measure on csr format datatype

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, similarity

I have a 22 million dataframe for training, where I applied tf-idf vectoriser, The resultant vector is in csr-format. Now, I have to apply the tfidf.transform on the test data and compare each row in the test data to each row in the training data with some similarity measure. How can I do this efficiently?

(On applying toarray() to the tfidf of training data, my system is crashing.)